# dimensionality reduction on 1 feature vector python

Tags: python, dimensionality-reduction

I have file with words and their frequency count. I want to reduce dimensionality may be by PCA in python. For example i have a file with a row as `156 170 177` and so on which depicts the different words and in the next row i have their count like `1 3 5 7 etc`. 
So my file is:

```
150 112 139 150 177
  1   2   3   10 15
```

I want to reduce the size of the data by performing dimensionality reduction so that I can remove extra words and their count. I followed PCA method. I performed standardization and then removed the mean out of it. Then I generated covariance matrix but the covariance matrix just gives me 1 X 1 matrix i.e. just 1 number. Can anyone guide me how can I approach for a solution in python

Comment: Can you please give some more details on data. Like number of rows. My experience with PCA says that it reduces number of features (columns) and make them equal to number of rows. So, if you have only single row, then you will get a single number only.

Comment: Hello sir, yes that is what probably I am thinking that PCA will reduce the number of features not the number of items. My main problem is given a set of words and their frequency (I can arrange them either row - wise or column wise). I want to reduce the number of items. For example if I have 100 words with their frequency I want to reduce it to some X number say 10. My data is as i have edited . I can arrange it column wise too. But main aim is to reduce the number of items or remove less imp items

Comment: can anyone suggest a direction?